# Why is my TArray<TPair<Integer, Double>> failing to sort using a custom comparer when some values are NaN?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a generic array of `TPair` records that contain an integer index and a double value. I am sorting this array by the value of each `TPair` by constructing a `TComparer<TPair<Integer, Double>>` that just calls the default `TComparer<Double>` on each `TPair`'s value. However, I get an Access Violation when I call the sort. The problem seems to be related to the fact that some of my values are `NaN`. I don't have control over the fact that some values will be `NaN`, so I need to work around that.

I tried to check for `NaN`'s before calling the default `TComparer` for doubles and instead replacing `NaN` with `Low(Integer)`, but that didn't help. At this point I've made a test application that reproduces the problem and I can see that the `TArray.QuickSort` function is performing thousands of comparisons for an array with 3 items... not sure what is going on.

Printing out the two pairs being compared in each call to either of the custom comparers gives this result:

```
[0] Left = (0, 1.00); Right = (1, NAN)
[1] Left = (1, NAN); Right = (1, NAN)
[2] Left = (2, 3.00); Right = (1, NAN)
[3] Left = (0, 0.00); Right = (1, NAN)
[4] Left = (0, 0.00); Right = (1, NAN)
...
[7328] Left = (0, 0.00); Right = (1, NAN)
[7329] Left = (58976, 0.00); Right = (1, NAN)
```

The access violation occurs on the subsequent call to my comparer after this last line is written out.

Here is a complete test application:

```
program Project51;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
   System.SysUtils, Generics.Collections, Generics.Defaults, Math;

type
   TIntDblPair = TPair<Integer, Double>;

var
   Comparer1, Comparer2 : IComparer<TIntDblPair>;
   ResultSet : TArray<TIntDblPair>;
   nCompares : Integer;

procedure Test(AComparer : IComparer<TIntDblPair>);
var
   I : Integer;
begin
   TArray.Sort<TIntDblPair>(ResultSet, AComparer);
   for I := 0 to Length(ResultSet) - 1 do
      WriteLn(Format('%d: %f', [ResultSet[I].Key, ResultSet[I].Value]));
   WriteLn;
end;

begin
   try
      SetLength(ResultSet, 3);
      ResultSet[0] := TIntDblPair.Create(0, 1);
      ResultSet[1] := TIntDblPair.Create(1, NaN);
      ResultSet[2] := TIntDblPair.Create(2, 3);

      nCompares := 0;
      Comparer1 := TComparer<TIntDblPair>.Construct(
                     function(const Left, Right: TIntDblPair): Integer
                     begin
                        WriteLn(Format('[%d] Left = (%d, %f); Right = (%d, %f)', [nCompares, Left.Key, Left.Value, Right.Key, Right.Value]));
                        Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Right.Value, Left.Value);
                        Inc(nCompares);
                     end
                   );
//      Test(Comparer1);

      nCompares := 0;
      Comparer2 := TComparer<TIntDblPair>.Construct(
                     function(const Left, Right: TIntDblPair): Integer
                     begin
                        WriteLn(Format('[%d] Left = (%d, %f); Right = (%d, %f)', [nCompares, Left.Key, Left.Value, Right.Key, Right.Value]));
                        if IsNaN(Right.Value) then
                           Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Low(Integer), Left.Value)
                        else if IsNaN(Left.Value) then
                           Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Right.Value, Low(Integer))
                        else
                           Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Right.Value, Left.Value);
                        Inc(nCompares);
                     end
                   );
      Test(Comparer2);

      Readln;
   except
      on E: Exception do
         Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
   end;
end.
```

Remy LeBeau pointed out that my checks in Comparer2 were not complete. Replacing Comparer2 with the following makes that sort call return the expected output. So it seems clear that the problem is when the default double comparer tries to compare NaNs. Is that a bug with the comparer implementation?

```
Comparer2 := TComparer<TIntDblPair>.Construct(
               function(const Left, Right: TIntDblPair): Integer
               begin
                  if IsNaN(Right.Value) and IsNaN(Left.Value) then
                     Result := 0
                  else if IsNaN(Right.Value) then
                     Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Low(Integer), Left.Value)
                  else if IsNaN(Left.Value) then
                     Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Right.Value, Low(Integer))
                  else
                     Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Right.Value, Left.Value);
               end
             );
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service. What have you done so far to try to debug the AV yourself? On which line exactly is the AV being raised? With which values exactly does the AV get raised? One thing I don't see you checking for in `Comparer2` is if BOTH `Left.Value` AND `Right.Value` are `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that mistake in Comparer2. Checking that case makes Comparer2 able to finish sorting the array. However, I still think it's worth getting to the bottom of why the default TComparer fails so badly when it tries to compare two NaNs. I'll edit my question to clarify more about debugging, sorry.

Comment: It didn't really matter to me where they ended up, and I would have fixed any ordering issues once I was able to get it to run and see the output. At this point my main question is: shouldn't this logic be inside the default comparer? It seems like a bug for it to not work out of the box on NaNs

Comment: Are you aware that nan <> nan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where to do want the `NaN`s positioned after the sort is done - the front or the back of the array? When you detect a `NaN`, DON'T call the default `TComparer` at all, just return `< 0` or `> 0` depending on where you want the `NaN` positioned relative to the other value (if BOTH are `NaN`, return 0 instead). And when you DO call the default `TComparer` for two non-`NaN` values, you have `Left.Value` and `Right.Value` backwards in both `Compare1` and `Compare2`.

Try something like this instead:

```pascal
Comparer2 := TComparer<TIntDblPair>.Construct(
               function(const Left, Right: TIntDblPair): Integer
               begin
                 if IsNaN(Left.Value) then begin
                   if IsNaN(Right.Value) then begin
                     Result := 0;
                     // or maybe:
                     // Result := TComparer<Integer>.Default.Compare(Left.Key, Right.Key);
                   end else begin
                     // To move Nan's to the front of the array, return -1 here
                     // To move Nan's to the back of the array, return 1 here
                     Result := ...;
                   end;
                 end
                 else if IsNaN(Right.Value) then begin
                   // To move Nan's to the front of the array, return 1 here
                   // To move Nan's to the back of the array, return -1 here
                   Result := ...;
                 end else begin
                   Result := TComparer<Double>.Default.Compare(Left.Value, Right.Value);
                   // and maybe:
                   // if Result = 0 then
                   //   Result := TComparer<Integer>.Default.Compare(Left.Key, Right.Key);
                 end;
               end
             );
```